# iPhone - Opening Maps and Dropping Pin with Non-English Title

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios5, maps, location

This question may seem to be repeated but it's not.

I want to open the Maps application and drop a pin on certain location with non-english title (say arabic one). I use the following url:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Title@30.036814,31.213998
```

This URL works. But if "Title" (the one written after q=) is an arabic string, nothing helps.
Is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way I found is to first [URL/percent encode your Arabic](http://www.motobit.com/util/url-encoder.asp), then replace `Title` with the %xx%yy mess.

For example:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%D9%89+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%AF+%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%86+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%88@30.036814,31.213998

Another option is to follow your `Title` link, and In the page's search bar (not the browser URL) replace `Title` with regular Arabic. Then you can click on the Link icon. But I found this method sometimes won't show the marker on the map.

Comment: The title to be replaced is variable is not a fixed one. I can't encode every location title in my list using the link you provided. The other option is not feasible since once my application goes into background mode, I can't follow the link sent to Maps application.

Comment: I meant to show an example with the encoding link. If there's not a library that does the encoding for you, you can write one or a function based on utf-8 rules.